# Nodejs express app not sending last-modified/exires header through HTTPS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-app-engine, caching

I've got a node-express backend app deployed through google cloud's app engine.

I'm serving some files through it and I'm trying to properly set up cache to be the typical access plus 1 week but adding last modified to the file actual modification to let the browser know it has to redownload it...

Here's how i set my headers

```
res.set({
    'Content-disposition' : 'inline',
    'Content-Type' : type,
    'Cache-Control' : 'public, max-age=604800, s-maxage=604800',
    'expires' : new Date(updated).toUTCString(),
    'Last-Modified' : new Date(updated).toUTCString()
})
```

When i try accessing the resource thorugh any browser or postman i keep getting the wrong Last-Modified

The date sent appears to be the creation date, so i debugged to check whether 'updated' was correct and it is.

Whilst trying to debug some various things I noticed something peculiar...
It works correctly through http but not through https...

What is happening?

Express is serving through plain http since it's only accessed insude GAE docker...
Therefore it must either be some weird GAE issue or something I'm not aware of about how browsers handle cache? (but then again even postman behaves the same)

EDIT:
Some more testing from different devices revealed another hint, It's not just Last-Modified, it's the whole headers..
Wen I access through https it just skips the whole headers entirely and gets the last request headers turning the status to 304 until the max-age has expired

ALSO clearing cache works for http but not for https

Comment: are you using GAE Standard or Flex?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is standard behaviour by design as all timestamps are made zero on deploy by app-engine. see:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168399701

I solved it by not setting the etag and last-modified headers. For example:

```
app.use("/", express.static(root, { etag: false, lastModified: false }));
```

Or for individual files:

```
app.get("/*", async (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile("index.html", { root, lastModified: false, etag: false });
});
```